# spark sqlContext read parquet S3 path not found

Tags: apache-spark

am using spark 2.3 scala 2.11.8 in AWS EMR and seeing s3 path not found but the path exists. aws s3 ls clearly shows the directory and content are fine

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: s3://dev-us-east-1/data/v1/output/20190115/individual/part-00000-b8450da0-15e9-482e-b588-08d6baa0637a-c000.snappy.parquet;

val df= sqlContext.read.parquet("s3://dev-us-east-1/data/v1/output/"""+dt+"""/individual/part-*.snappy.parquet")

Other folders/files load just fine with same code. Am wondering if there are file size limits or a memory issue masquerading as a path issue? I've also read about using s3a:// and s3n:// rather than s3:// but I am new to spark and a quick try changing my path to s3a:// got me an ACCESS DENIED exception

Comment: Check the access permissions on the file for your AWS account/credentials

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I can see but not read those files. Have never seen that problem in our s3 before